# Unable to upgrade rooted 4.2.2 with OTA update 4.3

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-4, ota-update, 4.3-jelly-bean

I bought my Nexus 4 from Google a while ago with 4.2.2 on it. It's using the stock rom, but it is rooted and has an unlocked bootloader.

When I try to install the OTA 4.3 update, the phone reboots and goes into Teamwin Recovery.

Then it looks like it tries to install it and then goes to the normal Teamwin recovery screen where I have to select Reboot > System to get back into the OS. And when I go back into the OS it's still 4.2.2.

What should I do? I think my best option is to manually install the update, but I don't know where it got downloaded to.